Suddenly getting application instability after waking laptop from sleep mode
Last Tuesday, I put my laptop into sleep mode before a power outage occurred, and after the 7 hours of no power, I booted it back up to find it seemingly okay, but quickly discovered an issue after some friends and I tried playing one of Discord's in-app games, "Colonists" (You know, the Settlers of Catan clone). Discord closed itself twice during the game, and when I checked event viewer, I found it was throwing up two OED warnings each time, each with Event-ID of 19, and with the following text:

"Check the remaining resource budget. Module exceeds resource budget, failed to AllocateFwCps, STATUS = Insufficient system resources exist to complete the API.."

Followed by another Warning entry, Event-ID of 4101, with the the following message:

"Display driver igfx stopped responding and has successfully recovered."


There were also two Kernel-General information logs after those warnings, with Event-ID of 16, with the following two blocks of text respectively:
1st:

"The access history in hive ??\C:\Users\Knight542\AppData\Local\Packages\AppUp.IntelGraphicsExperience_8j3eq9eme6ctt\SystemAppData\Helium\User.dat was cleared updating 9 keys and creating 1 modified pages."


2nd:

"The access history in hive ??\C:\Users\Knight542\Appdata\Local\Packages\AppUp.IntelGraphicsExperience_8j3eq9eme6ctt\SystemAppData\Helium\UserClasses.dat was cleared updating 1 keys and creating 1 modified pages."


Again, this happened twice, meaning all four of these entries in order whenever discord closed itself, for a total of eight entries.
I tried simply restarting my laptop, and running "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" followed by "SFC /Scannow", both at admin level in command prompt, and both returning no issues found. I thought that was the end of it, but throughout the week, I noticed my display was lagging a bit, and programs like chrome, discord, destiny 2, and even notepad, were sluggish.
Just tonight, I did a clean reinstall of both my integrated gpu drivers (intel), and my Nvidia drivers using DDU (DisplayDriverUninstaller), not connected to the internet, and then rebooted, ran DISM and SFC again, again returning no issues found, and things seemed to be better.
However, after stepping away and returning to my laptop after a few hours, I tried to re-maximize discord, and it closed on me again, and checking Event Viewer again, I saw the following two entries this time, both the exact same, and both at the time that discord closed.
Information entry, Event-ID of 19:

"Check the remaining resource budget. Module exceeds resource budget, failed to AllocateFwCps, STATUS = Insufficient system resources exist to complete the API.."


I asked a few friends who are good with computers, they think it could be a memory leak, but this has them really stumped, so I'm hoping to find some help here, instead, after my last issue with my laptop was resolved thanks to the Superuser community! If any more info is needed, please feel free to ask.
The Laptop's model is a HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop -16t-a000 CTO.
iGPU is simply listed as "Intel UHD Graphics", with 128mb of memory(vram?), and 8gb of shared memory(vram?)
Nvidia GPU is a GTX 1660ti with MAXQ Design, with 6gb of memory(vram?), and 8gb of shared memory(vram?)
The laptop itself has 16gb of RAM
Processor is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU at 2.60GHz (12CPUs), ~2.6GHz
BIOS F.24

First step for this sort of thing is usually to check what installed recently and roll that back or uninstall it, and check for and install any updated drivers and OS patches. Please do this and let us know whether or not the issues continue.

@music2myear thanks for the suggestion! I'll try it when I return home tomorrow. I'm positive there were no big updates (like windows or anything that would make the little update icon show up on the task bar) since a few weeks ago, but there always could have been a background driver update, I guess.

Alright, now that I'm finally back, I've gone ahead and rolled back the only recent update I could find (which would be five days prior to the first instance of the warnings). I guess now I just have to wait and see if anything changes, and update from there @music2myear .
